# MapReduce - Multiple outputs from an input and an array

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

**The goal**

I would like to have multiple output files from one input file and one array as described by the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aFMT.jpg).

**My idea**

I've thought about having a static attribute called "`check`" for the parent class `Program`.

```
public class Program
{
    //Attribute check
    private static String check = null;

    public static class ProgramMapper extends Reducer<Object, Text, Text, Text>{ 
     // mapping 
    }
    public static class ProgramReducer extends Reducer<Object, Text, Text, TextArray>{ 
     // reducing
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
     // main program
    }
// ...
```

In the `main` method, I would assign `check` to "a", "b", "c" in a loop:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

     // Array of checkpoints
        String[] arr = {"a", "c", "f"};

     // Loop for assigning check
        for(int j = 0; j<arr.length ; j++){
            check = arr[j];

        // job configuration
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
            Job job = new Job(conf, "Program");
            //...
            for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i){
                    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
            } 

      /* here I define multiple outputs */
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]+j));
            job.waitForCompletion(true);
            if (j == arr.length -1){
            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
```

The `reducer` would check if the key is equal to check

```
public static class ProgramReducer extends Reducer<Object, Text, Text, TextArray>{ 

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ArrayList<Text> result = new ArrayList<Text>();
        String key1 = key.toString();

     // check if the key is equal to check
        if ( key1.equals(check) ){
           result.add(new Text("o"));
        }else{
           result.add(new Text("x"));
        }

     // other reducing code
   }
}
```

**The problem**

`check` is never assigned to "a", "b", "c", so I have 3 output files all unchecked.

How could I solve this issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` method is running on a client but mappers and reducers are running on Hadoop nodes. To pass parameters to your mapreduce job you can use `Configuration` object.

In your `main` method set value:

```
conf.set("check", check);
```

And in reduce get it:

```
check = context.getConfiguration().get("check");
```

you can use method `Reducer.setup` to set this value only once before processing the data.